# Confusing about group and having clause with php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get all IDs from `table A` where all the Expiry date from `Table B` (`INNER JOIN ID = A_ID`) are `< today (2018-06-29)` but i'm not sure and a bit confusing for the query.

Based on my example (2018-06-29) i need to retrieve only `Name-4` because ALL Expiry date from `Table B are < 2018-06-29`

```
Table A

ID | Name   |
-------------
1  |  Name-1
2  |  Name-2
3  |  Name-3
4  |  Name-4
5  |  Name-5
6  |  Name-6
7  |  Name-7

Table B

ID | A_ID |  Expiry
-----------------------
1  |  1   |  2018-06-29
2  |  2   |  2018-07-29
3  |  2   |  2018-06-29
4  |  3   |  2018-07-29
5  |  3   |  2018-04-29
6  |  4   |  2018-05-29
7  |  4   |  2018-04-29
8  |  6   |  2018-09-29
9  |  6   |  2018-10-29
```

Comment: Join the tables then use a `where` I don't think you want to use `having` here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you need both the `GROUP BY` and the `HAVING` clauses.  Since you require that *all* expiry dates for a matching `A_ID` are less than a given date, you must check the `MAX()` expiry for that grouping.

```
SELECT ta.* FROM tableA ta JOIN tableB tb ON ta.ID = tb.A_ID
GROUP BY ta.id
HAVING MAX(Expiry) < '2018-06-20';
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8aace8/1)